# Set PHP 5.5.12 on Windows Server 2022 and MSSQL 2022

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm in charge of migrating a Windows 2008 web/application server (with Apache, PHP 5.5.12, sql-server 2012) to a new Windows Server 2022 machine, with MSSQL Server 2022.

I'm trying to migrate all the PHP applications on it but I've found out that I will need at least PHP 7.0 to connect to a MSSQL Server 2022. Is that correct?

If so, I need to rewrite all my applications (and library as well) from PHP 5.5.12 to PHP 7 or 8 which is very very complicated.

Some applications use xajax framework which is unsupported so I need to rewrite all of them and I have the same issue for other libraries as FPDF, MFPDF, PHP Excel or other old stuff. Any idea? Any tool for a less difficult passage?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I doubt you *need* to use the latest driver to connect to sql server 2022. TDS is usually pretty backward compatible. there might be issues with TLS 1.2 etc though. did you try actually connecting from your old php server to sql server 2022 and what happened

Comment: Why do you use the IIS tag when you actually didn't use it at all but Apache?

Comment: *"I need to rewrite all my applications (and library as well) from php 5.5.12 to..." YOu should be doing that anyway, support for PHP 5 ran out *ages* ago, with PHP 5.5 ending July 2016 (***7 years ago***).

Comment: Not much information to deal with, do you have custom code to connect to the DB, or do you have libraries and which

Comment: `I've found out`...quote and link to your source so we can verify it

Comment: What you've found so far doesn't seem to be correct. If you go by the official advice on [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix) then for "certified drivers" you need at least Microsoft PHP Drivers 5.10 for SQL Server to connect to SQL Server 2022 and those drivers  require PHP 7.4.0+ (as opposed to PHP 7.0).